# String index comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am having issues understanding this concept. I am trying to use `[-1]` index of `message[-1]` and compare it to the first index `message[0]` to compare the first letter and the last letter of a string in the function.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    message = " "
    if message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

Comment: Why are you re-instantiating your `message` variable using `message = " "`?
It will then always be string `" "` .

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your message to the same value every time.  You need to instead use the message that is passed to the function.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    if message and message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))

True
False
False
```

You can also get the same result with less work by recognizing that you're performing a test and returning the result of that test.

```
def first_and_last_improved(message):
    return message[0] == message[-1] if message else False
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are initialising the message = " " inside the function so no matter what you sent as a parameter to function it will always initialise it. Remove that line and you will get the expected output.

Comment: With one exception: When you pass it an empty container like `""`, it'll crash with an `IndexError` because `message[0]` is still invalid. Asker will still need to perform handling for this case.

Comment: Right. Adding extra check will help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are overwriting message variable. So whatever you pass to the function returns the same result.
You can think of a string of array of chars. In Haskell string is actually array of chars.
For example... "str" would be ["s", "t", "r"]. So "str"[0] returns s, while -1 returns r.

Also your code can be short by like this.

```
def first_and_last(message):
    return message[0] == message[-1]
```

Comment: This is elegant but be sure to add a check in case message is an empty string.  The function will throw an error if you check for an index in an empty string.  Since an empty string is not an unreasonable argument, it's probably best to handle it more gracefully.